# JsonNode.isBigInteger() returns false on any number

Tags: java, biginteger, jackson-databind

I have created a REST service that is looking for certain objects in the database.
Objects are identified either by ID or by name. ID is a BigInteger (up to 256 bits).
I have this piece of code in my controller:

```
for(JsonNode node : arrayNode) {
    if(node.isBigInteger()) {
       resultList.add(repository.getById(node.bigIntegerValue()));
    } else if(node.isTextual()) {
       resultList.add(repository.getByName(node.textValue()));
    } else {
        // skip it
    }
}
```

If in the request I give only names it works as expected, but if I specify numeric values, isBigInteger() always return false.
Unfortunately, there is no Javadoc for this function in Jackson.
Have anybody used this function? Is there is a bug there or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If the IDs are small enough that they don't need a BigInteger to fit, Jackson almost certainly is not deserializing them that way. There's no way for it to know, at this low a level, that you want BigIntegers all the time.

This is one of the reasons we deserialize data like that into model classes, to give hints about things like that.